# How to handle database connection down in GWT application

Tags: gwt

I handle a website which is designed in GWT and I want to check if database connection goes down in between accessing the website. If database connection is down I want to give message as cannot connect to server.

Can anybody suggest what will be the best way to handle this?

I know the `onFailure(Throwable t)` method on `AsyncCallback` is there. This method is called when the RPC fails for any reason, including (but not limited to) loss of connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not throw a meaningful exception from the RPC service on DB failure and handle the scenario inside onFailure of GWT RPC? You should extend AsyncCallback and handle all such general failure conditions (DB/NW failure etc...) at a single place and subclass this callback everywhere instead of defining new AsyncCallback instances each time.

Comment: Hi Ashwin.. thanks a lot for reply. Can you provide an example for failure cases ?

Comment: That's for you to find out. The answer will depend on which libraries/frameworks/DB's you are using. It works best if you handle all the errors within your RPC servlet call and throw a custom exception with a descriptive error message, that can be relayed to the UI.